# How do you group a large amount of specific URLs together in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

How do you group a large amount of specific URLs together in Google Analytics?

Each URL is specific and doesn't have a similar URL structure.

I tried content grouping but it only allows (I believe 20-50).

Stan

Comment: Two questions: what are you hoping to do with your grouped URLs, and how do you have GA implemented (in particular, via Google Tag Manager or not)?

Comment: I want to do a comparison report for those URLs. Those URLs are new posts that I just published and I want to track if there were any increase in page views, conversion, etc when they were first published. Yes, I have GTM installed.

Answer (score -1):

Per your last comment, here is a guide for "How To Get Data For A Specific List Of URLs In Google Analytics", hope this helps: https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/15102-google-analytics-excel-urls.html

Comment: An answer consisting entirely of a link is not high quality. Please edit this to summarize the instructions. Answers here ideally are fairly self-contained and don't require you to click off. Links should be used mostly for reference and further reading.